# Prevent a property in model to show up in query string

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-2

In asp.net mvc if I have a model like below:

```
public class MyModel
{
public string Name {get; set;}
public string MySecretProperty {get { return "123"; } }
}
```

In my controller :

```
MyModel model = new MyModel();
....
RedirectToAction("home", model);
```

The Url generated will be :

```
home?Name=xyz&MySecretPropert=123
```

Is there a way to hide a property to show up in query string using an attribute? I still want to use the property in the view and want it to remain part of the model but just don't want to show it in the query string.

The only option I can think of is to make a another class and not include the secret property in there and then use that class for the redirect and then again rebuild the full model by mapping the properties using an auto mapper or similar.

Is there any elegant way to do it? An attribute would be perfect to stick to the property like [HideDuringRedirect].

Answer (score 2):

You can redirect to action with an anonymous route object as,

```
return RedirectToAction("home", new {model.Name });
```

This will not include the secret property in the querystring. `MyModel` can still be used in redirected action to be populated.

hope this helps.